# Invalid signature: Bittrex Api - Python 3.10

Tags: authentication, hash, encode

I keep receiving an error when calling the bittrex api (v3).

My signature does not seem to be correct, but i do not know why.

I've been spending a lot of time on this but don't seem to get to the issue.

I have the feeling that something is wrong with my hash encoding, but can't seem to figure out what.

Could you help me?

please find the code i use below.

The content-hash is taken from bittrex.

```
import json
import requests
import time
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

unixtime = int(time.time() * 1000)
Api_Timestamp = str(unixtime)
Api_Key = '1234'
Api_secret ='1234'
uri = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/balances'
Api_Content_hash =   'cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e'
Api_subaccount = ''

Api_Signature = Api_Timestamp+uri+'GET'+Api_Content_hash+Api_subaccount
Api_Signature_encoded = hmac.new(Api_secret.encode(), Api_Signature.encode(),    hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

response_orders = requests.get(url=uri, headers={'Accept':'application/json','Api-Key':Api_Key, 'Api-Timestamp':Api_Timestamp, 'Api-Content-Hash':Api_Content_hash, 'Api-Signature':Api_Signature_encoded, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json()

print(response_orders)`
```